# How do I test a database connection in Django?

Tags: python, database, django

How do I test a database connection for Django? For example to make sure that the username and password of the database is correct.

Or if it is easier, where do I "catch" the database error when database connection fails ?

I have a scenario where database connection parameters is defined in a form by user. I need to make sure the username/password is correct and database must connect successfully before proceeding.

I can't seem to find any documentation anywhere, as most articles assume that the database connection is always successful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write a [middleware ("How Django processes a request")](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2006/jun/13/how-django-processes-request/) which will check for the database connection and redirect to your edit form.

```
class DbCheckMiddleware(object):

    def process_request(self, request):
        try:
            "Some DB Code"
            success = True
        except:
            success = False                

        request.db_connection_successful = success
```

Cache 'db_connection_successful' for performance.

Comment: Thank you for answering, I was attempting something similar.