# Show instant error page when database host is unavailable - django

Tags: python, django

I want to show instant error page when database host is unavailable. Default behavior for django is that ,when user requests , it takes long time and then displays error page.

Is there is any way to display some error instantly when database host is unreachable or database host is invalid with django without any delay ? Any suggestions ?

Comment: Maybe you can configure that in your webserver (Apache, Nginx,ed)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep checking the socket connection  status continuously in a script that will inform you regarding the same.
In case you are more concerned with the performance issues then you can make use of a in memory caching system like redis etc.

cheers :-)

Answer (score 0):

you could do a check for the database during django's init time.
a good place to do that would be in a module that is loaded with runserver. for example, your `urls.py` or a `router.py` id you have one.

The following snippet is taken from my answer to SO question [Testing postgres database accessibility from django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7548301/testing-postgres-database-accessibility-from-django/26086554#26086554)

```
from django.db import connections
conn = connections['default']
try:
    c = conn.cursor() #this will take some time if error
except OperationalError:
    reachable = False
else:
    reachable = True
```

The code checks if the database is available or not. you could write your logic based on the value of `reachable`

Comment: the line `c = conn.cursor()` takes long time to execute. And this is not what I am looking for.

Comment: @Fledgling, This is a one-time logic that is performed when django boots up. You could have instant error based on the value of `reachable` (put it in a shared location). The downside is that if your database fails any time after that, there is no way of finding that out. you are better off with some monitoring tools like Nagios for continuos monitoring.